# Strange problem with custom options

Tags: magento-1.7, products-management, custom-options

i developed a module that automatically imports simple products to magento. Furthermore it  adds custom options for every simple product.

As i can see in the database everything is working fine. My products are there and also the custom options.

The big problem now is, that these custom options are not visible in magento backend or frontend. If i add an additional custom option manually to any product, then the automatical created options also appear in backend and frontend. Strange thing.

Here you can see my function to create custom options for a given product. Is there anything wrong?

THX

```
protected function _createCustomOptionsForProduct($product, $event){
    try{
        // create custom options for given product
        $options = array(
            //'is_delete' => '',
            //'previous_type' => '',
            //'previous_group' => 'select',
            //'id' => '1',
            //'option_id' => '0',
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'title' => 'Price Category',
            'type' => 'drop_down',
            'is_require' => true,
            'sort_order' => '1',
            'values' => array()
        );

        // iterate over pricecategories and their containing price models
        $counter = 1;
        if(count($event->getData('priceCategories')) > 1) {
            foreach($event->getData('priceCategories') as $priceCategory ) {

                foreach($priceCategory->getData('priceModels') as $priceModel){

                    // check if price model is active otherwise skip it
                    if($priceModel->getData('active') == true){
                        // fill values array of custom option
                        // containing price category and price model
                        $options['values'][] = array(
                            //'option_type_id' => '-1',
                            //'is_delete' => '',
                            'title' => $priceCategory->getData('name') . ' - ' . $priceModel->getData('name') ,
                            'price' => number_format( $priceModel->getData('price')/100, 2 ),
                            'price_type' => 'fixed',
                            'sku' => $priceModel->getData('key'), // price model key as sku
                            'sort_order' => $counter
                        );
                    }
                    $counter++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            foreach($event->getData('priceCategories')->getData('priceModels') as $priceModel){
                // check if price model is active otherwise skip it
                if($priceModel->getData('active') == true){
                    // fill values array of custom option
                    // containing price category and price model
                    $options['values'][] = array(
                        //'option_type_id' => '-1',
                        //'is_delete' => '',
                        'title' => $event->getData('priceCategories')->getData('name') . ' - ' . $priceModel->getData('name') ,
                        'price' => number_format( $priceModel->getData('price')/100, 2 ),
                        'price_type' => 'fixed',
                        'sku' => $priceModel->getData('key'), // price model key as sku
                        'sort_order' => $counter
                    );
                }
                $counter++;
            }
        }

        if(count($options['values']) > 0 && !$product->getOptionsReadonly()) {

            $product->setHasOptions(1);

            $opt = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option');
            $opt->setProduct($product);
            $opt->addOption($options);
            $opt->saveOptions();

            //$product->setProductOptions(array($options));

            $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);

            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }catch (Exception $e){
        Mage::log('Error: could not create custom ticket / product options for '.
            $product->getName(), ZEND_LOG::CRIT, 'blafoo.log', false);

        Mage::log($e->getMessage(), ZEND_LOG::CRIT, 'blafoo.log', false);

        return false;
    }
```

Deleting caches or reindexing data didn't help.

Comment: Wonder if you're just missing a simple `$product->save()` after the options have been applied.

Comment: No its there outside of this function. :-( Any other hints?

Comment: @AndreAusB did you try it without commenting out the line `$product->setProductOptions(array($options))`

Comment: See this answer: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/10118/146 It may help explaining to what the problem is about creating custom options using the save events.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply set the options against a product and then call save on a product as the options are created in the `_afterSave`. After creating your options array simply set that the product has options, attach the options and then continue with your normal save process.

```
$product->setProductOptions($options);
$product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
```

Forget about creating the options as the product model should do this for you, so you no longer need the following code.

```
$opt = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option');
$opt->setProduct($product);
$opt->addOption($options);
$opt->saveOptions();
```