# Grouped product or configurable product?

Tags: configurable-product, ce-1.8.1.0, grouped-products

I know it's frequently asking question. But I have a different problem related this.

In my store customer will pay different price by color and size.

For example:

X product: Blue, S: $500
M product: Blue, L: $1500
Y product: Yellow, S: $550
Z product: Green, L: $800
T product: Green, XXL: $1800

Which product type I need to use? Grouped or configurable?

Comment: are all the different products or same product?

Comment: @DRAJI same product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the price is the only constraint I would say configurable.
You can set the prices for each attribute combination (size and color). It is not the best way of doing it but it's possible.

I don't even see why you would want to use grouped products here. It's not like you offer a group of products that contain product X- Blue-S and product Y-Blue-L.

You may also consider using custom options instead of configurable products.
[Here are more details about pros/cons for this approach.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/10935/146)

Comment: What's the best way so? Creating different products?

Comment: Like I said.. I would go with configurable products. Of course for that you will need a simple product for each combination of size and color.