# Stock status of a certain size

Tags: stock

in my site is SIZE display as a custom option, if now I have the products with size of a certain size is not in stock, change the state of this size is not on the active

Possible? let me know

Thanks

Comment: i think you can use configurable products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `default custom  option is manage qty of variance that means one of a size`.

It will better to  use `configurable products` ,if  want to managed inventory of each size.

More details on 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/difference-between-custom-variants-options-and-configurable-product-type

and @Marius post  [Product Types: custom options vs bundle vs configurable](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10935/product-types-custom-options-vs-bundle-vs-configurable)

Comment: so, i have now more 1000 simple products with custom options, how i can do this for simple products? maybe possible add new field or value and if value = 0, size in frontend is disable or somehow