# Complex Configuration Product

Tags: magento-1.7, product, attributes, configurable-product, product-attribute

I have created on configuration product, Price change on base 5 different attributes
( country, size, width, depth and metal) Product is based on ring.

Problem i am facing is that due to this 5 attribute structure. I must have to create lots of simple product, 1000 around.  country X size X width X depth X metal =1000 around

I don't think client will going to accept this flow, he will not going to create 1000 simple product.

Can anyone has better idea?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/10935/146

Comment: If the items exist as real products laying in a shaft, you/he should do this. Creating 1000 products programmatically is no problem. If you create the products you can just go with custom options as Marius proposed.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize what is in the link as posted as a comment...
You can always use custom options or bundle products, but each approach has his pros and cons.
There is also the option to create a product generator based on some configurations.
I mean let you client create only the configurable product and then, through your custom code, auto-generated the simple products needed. This may make your client happy :).

You can also take the long road and create your own product type that will behave in a similar way a configurable product does, but behind the scene it will be your code controlling it.  This is an option but I wouldn't go down this road. It may be very long and painful.