# How to add different prices for different product sizes?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have read many posts here, but didn't found my answer.
I have a perfume store and want to add different price on each perfume size. I don't want to create simple products for each size because this will be time consuming and will create duplicate pages. What i need is to open a product ( lets say perfume: "Gucci" and to be able to add size options with corresponding prices, e.g. :

50ml - price: $50

75ml - price: $70

100ml - price: $100

Can you tell me what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case,you can use  Custom options,Make a dropdown custom option and as per as magento,you can set different price for custom option of each custom value.

Note:it does not manage inventory  as option wise

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom Options:

- Create a simple product with $50 price.
- Create a custom option with type Drop-down.
- Add options with fixed prices.

But I use combination of simple and configurable products because for example 50ml Gucci perfume can ran out of stock while others are still in stock. Plus you can upload different images for each capacity. It may be a little time consuming but it has a lot of benefits than Custom Options.

There's more explanations of pros/cons of each approach here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/10936/4276

Comment: Yes, you are right, but  for example if 30ml Gucci is out of Stock, you can just remove the option: "30ml" from custom options. This way is much easier and faster if you have many products.

Comment: But you have to check quantity every day or less, or write a cron job to do that for you. Magento will automatically disable out of stocks if you use simple products. Well, it's your choice after all. Please let us know Custom Options suite you or not.