# How to add different prices for the same product?

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I want to add different prices for the same product, based on the size of apparrel the customer selects.

For example:

Kids sizes £10

Adults sizes £15

How do I do this? As all I am able to do currently is add a fixed price for each size.

Comment: so are you referring to configurable product??? please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Custom options,Make a dropdown custom option and as per as magento,you can set different price for custom option of each custom value.

Note:it does not manage inventory as option wise.

[answer reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93987/how-to-add-different-prices-for-different-product-sizes?rq=1)

Comment: I have tried this, however it just adds that price as a discount. For example on the product price tab, there is a price there of £20, as a price must be included. But when I go to the Custom Options tab and put £15 next to Kids sizes, it appears on the actual page as Price: £20 - £15. If this makes sense?

Comment: it work actual price + custom option price..

Comment: Is there a way of just showing the custom option price and not the actual price?

Comment: @mattg1502 did you find the solution for this?