# custom option for all product

Tags: product, custom-options

i want to add custom option for all product say ring size:7,6,5,4,3

i want to show if for all product types with attribute set as ring , i tried adding as custom option but in this way we have to add for all products , any easy way too show it as drop down fro all product

Bascially it drop down and user have to select it

Comment: Maybe you should look into configurable products.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can do this by magento event observer.try trigger an event on `catalog_product_prepare_save` observer  check product attribute set is ring

Study about [Creating Custom Option on Product Save](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9480/creating-custom-option-on-product-save)

On This function you need check your attribute set for product  is ring  and your custom option  is exit on not

See some logic:

```
$exit=false;

    $options = $product->getOptions();
    if ($options){
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $optionType = $option->getType();
        if ($optionType == 'drop_down' && $option->getTitle()=='Ring' ) :
            $exit=true;
            break;
        endif;

        }
    }

    if($exit==false):
    $newOption = array(
        'title' => "Ring",
        'type' => 'drop_down',
        'is_require' => 1,
        'sort_order' => 20,
        'values' => array(
            array(
                'title' => "7",
                'price' => 42.00,
                'price_type' => 'fixed',
                'sku' => "",
                'sort_order' => '1'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => "6",
                'price' => 50,
                'price_type' => 'percent',
                'sku' => "",
                'sort_order' => '2'
            )
        )
    );

    //don't use it like this because it has no effect
    //$product->setProductOptions($options);
    $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
    //use it this way. Populate `$product->getOptionInstance()` directly
    $product->getOptionInstance()->addOption($newOption);
    //don't forget to state that the product has custom options
    $product->setHasOptions(true);

    endif;
```

Comment: i there any way via magento admin

Comment: please use magento api...

Comment: magento api ??..

Comment: yes...usign api you need save magento product

Answer (score 1):

When I cannot add some product options using configurable product, I create the custom option in one product, and use the following to duplicate it to another product:

```
class Company_Module_Model_Resource_Catalog_Product_Option extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Option
{

    /**
     * Duplicate custom options from productA to productB
     *
     * @param int|string $productA sku or id
     * @param int|string $productB sku or id
     * @param string|array $optionTitle the title to duplicate    
     * @return array
     */
    public function duplicateOptions($productA, $productB, $optionTitle)
    {
        if (!is_int($productA)) {
            $productIdA = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')->getIdbySku($productA);
        }
        if (!is_int($productB)) {
            $productIdB = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')->getIdbySku($productB);
        } 

        $write  = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
        $read   = $this->_getReadAdapter();
        $option = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option');

        $optionsCond = array();
        $optionsData = array();

        $cond = is_array($optionTitle) ?
                    '`t2`.`title` IN (?)' :
                    '`t2`.`title` = ?';
        $select  = $read->select()
            ->from(array('t1'=>$this->getMainTable()))
            ->joinLeft(array('t2'=>$this->getTable('catalog/product_option_title')),
                        "`t1`.`option_id` = `t2`.`option_id`",
                        null)
            ->where($cond, $optionTitle)
            ->where('`t1`.`product_id` = ?', $productIdA);
        $query = $read->query($select);

        while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
            $optionsData[$row['option_id']] = $row;
            $optionsData[$row['option_id']]['product_id'] = $productIdB;
            unset($optionsData[$row['option_id']]['option_id']); // auto optionIdB when insert
        }

        // insert option to product B
        foreach ($optionsData as $optionIdA => $data) {
            $write->insert($this->getMainTable(), $data);
            $optionsCond[$optionIdA] = $write->lastInsertId($this->getMainTable()); // optionIdB
        }

        // insert option_type title, price, and value to product B
        foreach ($optionsCond as $optionIdA => $optionIdB) {
            // title
            $table = $this->getTable('catalog/product_option_title');

            $select = $read->select()
                ->from($table, array(new Zend_Db_Expr($optionIdB), 'store_id', 'title'))
                ->where('option_id = ?', $optionIdA);

            $insertSelect = $write->insertFromSelect(
                $select,
                $table,
                array('option_id', 'store_id', 'title'),
                Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INSERT_ON_DUPLICATE
            );
            $write->query($insertSelect);

            // price
            $table = $this->getTable('catalog/product_option_price');

            $select = $read->select()
                ->from($table, array(new Zend_Db_Expr($optionIdB), 'store_id', 'price', 'price_type'))
                ->where('option_id = ?', $optionIdA);

            $insertSelect = $write->insertFromSelect(
                $select, 
                $table,
                array('option_id', 'store_id', 'price', 'price_type'),
                Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INSERT_ON_DUPLICATE
            );
            $write->query($insertSelect);

            $option->getValueInstance()->duplicate($optionIdA, $optionIdB);
        }

        return $optionsData;
    }        
}
```

To call it:

```
$result = Mage::getResourceSingleton('company/module_product')->duplicateOptions($sourceProductId, $targetProductId, 'Ring Size');
```