# how to set similar custom option for all products once?

Tags: price, custom-options, products

I have many categories like rings, pendents, chains in my site.
the products under category **rings** have custom option like
Quality grade - A, B, C ....
size          - 5,6,7 .....
metal         - Gold , silver, platinum all with some extra prices

Is there any way to create custom option once for the product and i can use them in all other product under rings.

As now i have to add same options again n again when i add products? Different custom option for different category.

**Please suggest**

Comment: use configurable product instead of custom option

Comment: @sonal, do each of these custom options on a ring have its own (and *different*) amount added to the price?

Comment: yes, price varies with custom options for each ring

Answer (score 0):

You can create an attribute by option

- Grade (with values "A", "B", "C", etc.)
- Metal (with values "gold", "silver", etc.)
- Size (with values "5", "6", "7", etc.)

Then create simple products for all variation

- ring variation 1 : grade A, Metal Gold, Size 5
- ring variation 2 : grade B, Metal Gold, Size 5
- ring variation 3 : grade B, Metal Silver, Size 5
- etc.

Then create configurable product on attributes grade, size and metal.
You'll just have to link simple products to enable an option.

Comment: But in this case if the one ring comes in 10 variation then i have to add it ten  times as simple product and after that i should create a configurable product ,right?

Comment: Yes, but it is easier to duplicate products and change only one attribute.
You can also mass import simple products in your backend with a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no interface in the admin to copy custom options, unfortunately. However, it can be done easily with a script or extension. I answered a question on how to programmatically add custom options not long ago.

Check it out: [Add custom options to products programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61172/add-custom-options-to-products-programmatically/61247#61247)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this last night so i'm gonna show you how i did it, perhaps this could help someone, in my scenario i have to add for a custom category the option of unassembled-preassembled product, with a 6% increment, as you'll see you can setup your option as you want, you don't have to spend money if you know a little of stored procedured and cursors. Ok so here is the code: i'll put 22 as the category_id in your case it should be probably a different category_id.

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE `customOptions`()
    BEGIN
      DECLARE finished integer DEFAULT 0;
      DECLARE v_id integer;
      DECLARE v_option integer;
      DECLARE v_option_type_one integer;
      DECLARE v_option_type_two integer;
      DECLARE product_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT (`product_id`) FROM `catalog_category_product` WHERE `category_id` IN (22);
      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
        SET finished = 1;
      OPEN product_cursor;
      get_product: LOOP
        FETCH product_cursor INTO v_id;
        IF finished = 1 THEN
          LEAVE get_product;
        END IF;
        -- build email list
        INSERT
          INTO `catalog_product_option`
        VALUES
          (NULL, v_id, 'drop_down', 1, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, 0, 1);
        SET v_option = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        INSERT
          INTO `catalog_product_option_title`
        VALUES
          (NULL, v_option, 0, 'preassembled');
        INSERT
          INTO `catalog_product_option_type_value`
        VALUES
          (NULL, v_option, NULL, 1);
        SET v_option_type_one = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        INSERT
          INTO `catalog_product_option_type_value`
        VALUES
          (NULL, v_option, NULL, 2);
        SET v_option_type_two = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        INSERT
          INTO `catalog_product_option_type_price`
        VALUES
          (NULL, v_option_type_one, 0, 0, 'percent');
        INSERT
          INTO `catalog_product_option_type_price`
        VALUES
          (NULL, v_option_type_two, 0, 6, 'percent');
        INSERT
          INTO `catalog_product_option_type_title`
        VALUES
          (NULL, v_option_type_one, 0, 'No');
        INSERT
          INTO `catalog_product_option_type_title`
        VALUES
          (NULL, v_option_type_two, 0, 'Yes');
      END LOOP get_product;
      CLOSE product_cursor;
        update catalog_product_entity set has_options=1,required_options=1 where entity_id in (SELECT DISTINCT (`product_id`) FROM `catalog_category_product` WHERE `category_id` IN (22));

    END;
```

So, that's pretty much all, hope this could help someone, have a great day!

Comment: of course you then type php bin/magento indexer:reindex and clean cache and you're all set.

Comment: you could also do that with a php script, but as i feel comfortable with sql is easier for me also i learn about the magento structure.